# How to detect if the app has been killed using a service? android

Tags: android

How do i detect if the app has been killed? 
i have found a solution which is call activity on **onDestroy**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionStablizer.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    // code here
}
```

it is working fine on galaxy note 3 (4.4.2) but not working on android emulator (android 4.2.2), galaxy y duos (2.3.6) and htc desire (4.0.2)

so i found another solution-

run a background service which detects when app gets destroyed and launch the activity again like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040339/how-to-know-when-my-app-has-been-killed)

i have the exact implementation but it doesn't do anything? where am i wrong? my code is the same as in the link

Answer (score 2):

> where am I wrong

**You are wrong trying to reopen your app once it's been destroyed**. This is a hacky behavior...

Nevertheless, you can achieve your goal by using [alarm manager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and set an alarm for every second or so, to check if your app is alive if it's not you can bring it back.

Also, pay attention:

> Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

### I strongly recommend to not use my solution, nor attempting to find one.

Comment: @Toxic You can find a good tutorial at [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: @Toxic from in the broadcast receiver class you can start an activity or a service and execute what code you like. Activity will be seen to the user. Service will not

Answer (score 1):

If the app is removed from recent apps by user then you can get a notification from OS by overriding ***`onTaskRemoved`*** method in your service and take respective action. In general Android never kills any app unless otherwise in a low memory condition. In such case callbacks will be given to save the state of your application provided you handle all such callbacks.

Comment: i have tried that too so i have decided to stick to notification manager. i will accept your answer if you solve my problem. invite me to chat

Comment: I am using stack exchange Android app currently. May be after sometime will try to chat