# How to execute code before Android app is killed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an Android app that connects to surrounding devices **currently running the same app**, **even if in background**.

To do this, I use WiF-Direct to advertise the fact that I am currently running said application.

Therefore I need to stop advertising this as soon as the app is killed.

- `onDestroy()` cannot be used since it is not guaranteed to be called.
- `onStop()` and `onPause()` cannot be used since the app is still running.

How can I achieve this?

Currently the service is still being advertised even when the application is closed/killed.

Comment: Do you have an extended Application class?

Comment: Can you check if the app is still running in WiFi Direct before broadcasting from it?

Comment: @liminal The service advertising is launched by the application itself when it launches. So it is obviously running at that time. It's a one time process, not a continuous one.

Comment: @cricket_007 Should I?

Comment: Do you `finish()` your main activity explicitly or let Android destroy it when the device is low on memory? If the former is true, I believe you can guarantee the onDestroy being called.

Comment: I don't know how the end user will kill it, it may "CLOSE ALL" apps, it may swipe it, etc... In any case I've tested it and onDestroy() is not always called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a Service.

Start a service when your app was started. 
Override the onTaskRemoved method

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
{
}
```

In this method do what you have to do.
More detailed answer can be found here: [How to know when my app has been killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040339/how-to-know-when-my-app-has-been-killed) (2 answer)

Comment: I'm going to look into this, will get back with the results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best implementation might be to have another service running that queries the your app is in foreground(i.e. running)

You can run the query to check periodically say every 60 sec. Then if the app isn't running. You can stop the WiFi Direct service and subsequently stop self.

Comment: Another service running seems like a possible solution, but there should be something more efficient than just checking every so often if my app is still running. Thanks