# android - Determine if the app is killed by swiping out from the recent activity

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project, which include VOIP functionality. I want to end the active call if the user kill the app by swiping out from the recent activity list. Usually, when the recent activity list is open, `onPause` and `onStop` callback is triggered and after that `onDestroy`. But when I try ending call in `onDestroy` nothing happened, the active call is not ended. But when I end the call in `onStop`, I am successfully end the call. But that is not what I want. I want to end the call in `onDestroy` callback .

However, what I want to do is to end the call when the user kill the app by swiping out the app from recent activity list.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33078782/3027833