# How can I detect app kill on Android 8.0 Oreo API 26 and after

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I need to detect application process kill to run some clean up tasks on server side.

The solutions which is mentioned on popular questions are no longer works on Android 8 or later. Is there a way to detect application kill on Android 8 or later?

Pre-Android 8 solutions:

- [How to know when my app has been killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040339/how-to-know-when-my-app-has-been-killed)
- [How to handle code when app is killed by swiping in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568315/how-to-handle-code-when-app-is-killed-by-swiping-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You could use same solutions you linked, but starting from Oreo a SERVICE should be started as FOREGROUND_SERVICE or it will be killed withing 5 seconds from the System.
So you can reuse 90% of previous code but you need to do changes according to new Oreo requirements.

However if the App is killed from "Android Settings --> Apps" page by selecting the "Terminate" button, even all Background Services are killed in the same time, so if this case occurs those methods will not work anymore.