# Life cycle event for manually killed app by a user in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

Here is the situation I have got stuck. I want to know if there is any call back available if user manually kills the app (Like activity life cycle methods). Basically, I want to know weather the app is running or not. In running case, App may have 2 cases

1. ForeGround
2. Background

And third case can be app is not running at all. I have searched and I found if I use below code I can check weather app is in process.The code is below which I have used

```
 ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) 
 context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningApps = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (runningApps != null) {
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningApps) {
            if (processInfo.processName.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is returning true if the app is running (Foreground and background). And that is expected but the problem is when app is not background (app is manually killed by a user) not running at all, it is also returning true. 
    What I believe this is happening because I am using forground service. Weather the app is killed but the service of the app is still running that's why the code mentioned returning true. I think running forground service causes **Application Process** alive. 
My question is If this is the case, how can I check if app is not running at all after killing by a user manually.

Comment: if the app is not running, how is the code that checks this going to be executed?

Comment: Because this code is running inside forground service

Comment: there is no call back when there is any force close of your application

Comment: There is any alternative or some suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33078782/5077102 please go through this this may help

Comment: thank you for guiding me to the right direction. You direction did helped me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know when my app has been killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040339/how-to-know-when-my-app-has-been-killed)