# When shut down android app

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

How can i get when kil processing app . For Example [image: This Image]

When One customer going to kill my app . i want to learn this state so when app killing. onDestroy method doesn't working. I need alternative for it.

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("Activity","destroy");
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle code when app is killed by swiping in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568315/how-to-handle-code-when-app-is-killed-by-swiping-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can'd do this. The last lifecycle call which gets called last is the onPause. Nothing else is garanted.

As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16013646/5842844

> When a user or the system force stops your application, the entire
>   process is simply killed. There is no callback made to inform you that
>   this has happened.
>
> When the user uninstalls the app, at first the process is killed, then
>   your apk file and data directory are deleted, along with the records
>   in Package Manager that tell other apps which intent filters you've
>   registered for.

Comment: There is no way about my issue. I Cant do anything ? I need a solve it. Damn! Its bad idea .