# Xamarin Forms - Detect when app is closed / reopened

Tags: xamarin, onstart

Please could you explain how I can detect when an app is closed? I don't want to use only OnSleep as this is only background running, so it there a method for identifying when an app is exited in contract to the OnStart method?

Does OnDisappearing AND OnAppearing work just the same?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by closed? killed by os? and why do you need that? [lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle) - [How to detect if android app is force stopped or uninstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16013578/5228202).

Comment: Yes i mean kill the app. Well I've created a timer app so I need to know the DateTime the app was killed in order to add the difference when the app is opened... Unless there is any other way to continue a timer, maybe MongoDB side?

Comment: If the app process is already killed there is no callback so no way you can execute another command, you could maybe periodically save the timer or https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696962/5228202