# Convert an android app to be hidden

Tags: android, icons, hide

I am a new developer in android. I write a program with Main Activity that has 2 broadcastReceiver and 1 service. My app has an Icon, and I want to hide my launcher app icon from user and I want my app running in background.
I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204720/android-hidden-application), but when I remove Activity segment, got errors.
My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>
 <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="18" android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ray.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <service
        android:name=".LocalWordService"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </service>


    <receiver android:name=".MyScheduleReceiver" android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".MyStartServiceReceiver" >
    </receiver>


</application>
```

Comment: Hide your app from the user? Sounds pretty suspicious

Comment: Just delete the intent-filter lines from the Manifest file - 
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

Comment: My means is hide Icon from the user, not hiding in app list!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531926/726863

Comment: @Payeli, this is not work. I also moved MyScheduleReceiver and MyStartServiceReceiver in another packge, but this doesn't work..

Comment: @Lalit Poptani, this link same as link that i mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done.  A newly installed app is in the stopped state.  The only way to turn it on is to run an Activity in the app manually.  This is a security feature in Android.  This means no services and no broadcast receivers will be run until at least 1 activity has been launched.  Which means you need an Activity in the launcher.  Which means it will appear in the app list.

Comment: then, Doesn't [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204720/android-hidden-application) work?

Comment: Not on 3.0+.  The BroadcastReceiver will be stopped and won't fire until an activity in the app has been manually run.