# Not show application in installed applications in device settings in Android

Tags: android, android-settings

Is there any way so that I can avoid showing my application in the list of installed application in Android? I am trying to make this spy application which should not show up in the list of installed applications in the settings menu. Is there a way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204720/android-hidden-application like a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way so that I can avoid showing my application in the list of installed application in Android ?

No, for obvious privacy and security reasons.